# Azure Functions support for NewtonSoft custom convertors package in external library

Tags: c#, json.net, azure-functions

I am converting a small WebAPI functionality into an Azure Function.  I need to return a model that has multiple properties including a property of type MailAddress.

Because this type does not have a default constructor, before serializing it to JSON  I need to decorate the property with a custom JSONConverter.

```
[JsonProperty("alternateEmail")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(MailAddressConverter))]
public MailAddress alternateEmail { get; set; }
```

The  MailAddressConverter code can be found here :

```
http://code-smart.org.uk/techniques/serialising-constructor-less-net-types-e-g-mailaddress-using-newtonsoft-json-jsonconvert-in-the-json-net-library/
```

There is a difference within Azure Functions solution when I package the Converter-class in an external DLL or when I add the class inline to the run.csx file.  The custom Converter-class is not being executed when packaged (together with the domain model) , but when the same class is added inline to the run.csx file, the class is correctly serialized.

What is happening here?  It should have the same result.

Best regards,

Jens

Answer (score 0):

After restarting the App Service , the issue was solved.  There was a glitch somewhere...